# Limit involving unknown function:$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{f(x)}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

> Let $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ be a function s.t.:
> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{f(x)}=1$$
> Evaluate, if exist, and give arguments:
>
> $(a)$ $$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{e^{e^{f(x)}-1}-1}{x}$$ $(b)$ $$\lim _{x \to
>  0} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{|\cosh x-1|}}$$

My attempt:

$$1\pm\sin x=\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\pm\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)|-|\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)|}{f(x)}=1$$
$x\to 0\implies \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)>\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{f(x)}=1$$
We aren't allowed to use neither L'Hospital nor Taylor series, but $f'(0)=1$ clearly has to hold.

---

**Edit:** I found a typo. In the task $(a)$. It should've been:

$$\frac{e^{e^{f(x)}-1}-1}x\quad\text {instead of }\quad\frac{e^{e^{f(x)-1}}-1}x,$$

but the answer provided by Z. Ahmed is still correct.

---

We can do the following:

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}-\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}{f(x)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin(x)}{x\cdot\left(\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}\right)}\cdot\frac{x}{f(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}x\cdot\frac2{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}\cdot\frac{x}{f(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{f(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}x\\&=1\end{aligned}$$

Task $(a)$

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{e^{f(x)}-1}-1}x&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{e^{f(x)}-1}-1}{e^{f(x)}-1}\cdot\frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}\cdot\frac{f(x)}x=1\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}-\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}\to0$ as $x\to0$. Therefore, $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$. In fact, if $g(x)\to0$ and $g(x)/f(x)\to1$, then $f(x)=g(x)/(g(x)/f(x))\to 0/1=0$. From this you get that (a) diverges. Are you sure it is $f(x)-1$ in the exponent? It is a more interesting exercise with $f(x)$ in the exponent instead.

Comment: In the case of (b) then you do get to use the given limit more specifically. $\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}-\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}{f(x)}=\frac{2\sin(x)}{f(x)(\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(x)})}$. Since $\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}\to2$, then $\frac{\sin(x)}{f(x)}\to1$. But $\frac{\sin(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{x}{f(x)}$. So, $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to1$. Now you can write $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{ch}(x)-1}}=\frac{f(x)}{x}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\operatorname{ch}(x)-1}}$.

Comment: @OscarRascal, I apologise for my mistake it is, $$e^{e^{f(x)-1}}$$

Comment: Well, with $e^{e^{f(x)-1}}$ nothing changes. Since $f(x)\to0$, then $e^{e^{f(x)-1}}\to e^{e^{-1}}\neq1$. So (a) still doesn't exist. The reason why with $e^{f(x)}$ it becomes interesting is that in that case, like (b) both the numerator and denominator tend to zero. Then one gets to have to manipulate the limit to determine it.

Comment: What's $\operatorname{ch} x$?

Comment: @Lucas Henrique, I apologise, I forgot we use different notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{f(x)}=1$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/2}-(1-x)^{1/2}}{f(x)}=1$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{f(x)}=1 \implies f(x)=x+a(x^2)+...$$

Comment: We haven't used the big O notation so far.

Comment: OK you may see my edit.